# Creating branched linestring

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, shapely, fiona

I have a shapefile where a cable consists of multiple parts. In the example below the highlighted cable consists of three parts. I have exported the attribute table and am trying to write a Python code to connect the individual segments based on matching start/end coordinates.

[image]

I have so far been succesful in finding which segments should go together but now I need to actually connect them. A first attempt was made in which I collected the four unique points for the three segments together and wrote them back to a new shapefile using fiona and a shapely LineString. This however resulted in the following line.

[image]

What happens is that it creates a line through the 4 points based on the order they are in. I now realise that I need to connect the separate line segments. I'm thinking about collecting the segments that I want to connect together, create individual LineStrings from then and then merge them all together.

How can I do this with a branched line such as in the example here?